# Angular - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have a project with ASP.NET Core Web API backend and Angular-13 frontend.

The Web API have this end-point: https://localhost:5001/api/v1/admin/teachers

After login, when I pasted the generated bearer token to POSTMAN, it gives this result:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
        "full_name": "Jamilu Kingston",
        "account_number": "1234567821",
        "user_name": "kingston",
        "mobile_number": "08099889921",
    }
  ],
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 10,
  "total_pages": 1
}
```

From the Angular frontend, I have these code.

ANGULAR

teacher.service:

```
export class TeacherService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-type': 'application/json'}).set('Authorization',  `Bearer ${this.token}`)
  };

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
    ) { }

  getAllTeachers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'admin/teachers', this.httpOptions);
  }
}
```

teacher.component:

```
export class TeachertsComponent implements OnInit {
  allTeacherList: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private teacherService: TeacherService,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadAllTeachers();
  }

  loadAllTeachers(){
    this.teacherService.getAllTeachers().subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
       console.log(res);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.toastr.error(error.message);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I expected it to load all the teachers, but I got this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

When I checked the Developer Network I have this:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:5001/api/v1/admin/teachers
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: [::1]:5001
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-length: 0
date: Thu, 13 Jan 2022 10:03:27 GMT
server: Kestrel
www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"
:authority: localhost:5001
:method: GET
:path: /api/v1/admin/teachers
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
authorization: Bearer "something is here"
origin: http://localhost:4200
referer: http://localhost:4200/
```

From the Developer Network above Bearer token is there. Also when I did **console.log(`Bearer ${this.token}`);**

I also have it there.

It's not even getting to console.log(res);

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this method localStorage.getItem('token') return the correct token?

Comment: did try and debug the .NET application/endpoint?

Comment: @danvid - I have tested all the .NET application/endpoint on POSTMAN and everything was successful

Comment: If the token is not defined the server shouldn't be returning a 404. Does the endpoint exist, or do you have a typo somewhere? Nevertheless you should debug your .NET endpoint

Comment: @Den - How do you mean? As I set the token during login, I also check the localStorageto confirm

Comment: @Batajus - But the .NET endpoints are working on POSTMAN

Comment: headers are different in postman and the browser. Debug .NET with the browser

Comment: If the token should be the issue try to move the token loading and header creation directly in front of your http call to see if this resolves your issue

Comment: @midowu - in your localstorage what is the value of the param 'token'? Is this only a check.

Answer (score 0):

You have a misspeilling "Content-type". But since Content-Type is set to json by default and you don't have any content, try this syntax

```
const headerObj =new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Bearer ${this.token}");

httpOptions = {
    headers:headerObj
  };
```